# If a function is defined on the interval $(a, b)$, is the derivative necessarily defined at $a$ and $b$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am asked to prove something that assumes this. But is it true that derivative is necessarily defined at the "edges" of the domain of the definition of its function?

Does it matter if the original function is continuous on $(a, b)$?

Comment: The domain of the derivative of a function is always a subset of the domain of the function, so the derivative is *never* defined at $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Think about the examples of functions that are defined and continuous on open interval $(a,b) $ but not differentiable at $x=a,b $.

Comment: @GitGud the assignment doesn't say that the function isn't defined anywhere outside $(a, b)$, so it _could be_ defined, I'm just not told that it is.

Comment: Quite apart from the end-point problem, there are functions that are continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere. So your question is poorly posed.

Comment: @TravisJ Normally, I try to avoid fighting over edits that change nothing in the question, but just out of curiosity, why did you change "subsume" to "assume"? I mean, the thing that I'm given to prove doesn't assume that, it subsumes (as in, if proved to be true, then this statement would be a particular case of some larger claim).

Comment: @wvxvw, sorry if the edit lost meaning.  The word subsume means something else to me (so I apparently erroneously assumed that the word had been misused).  I can either change it back... or you can do it (you can always edit your own posts).  Sorry to cause any inconvenience.

Comment: @TravisJ no need. It's just one of those commonly misused words, and one of those rare cases when it was actually used properly :) so it is a bit ironic, but it doesn't matter since whether it was assumed, subsumed or presumed, the result would be the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a=0, b=\pi, f(x)=\csc(x)$ . . .

Answer (score 1):

no, absolutely not. For instance look at the function

$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x} ,x\in [0,1]
$$
and its derivative
$$
f(x)'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}
$$
which is clearly not defined at $0$.

bests

Comment: Thanks, although I'm going to accept Noah Schweber's answer (simply because he was first). All answers in my eye are good. I just have to pick one to make SO rules happy.

Answer (score 1):

Another case: $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is defined and continuous on $(0,1)$ but not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to accept Noah Schweber's answer just because it was the first one. Now I see that all answers are very nice, so there would be no other reason to prefer one. I'm just doing it to comply with SO rules. :)